# About polynomial value being perfect power.

Tags: number-theory

I have following problem, that I know that is true, but I don't know how to prove.

**For all polynomial with integer coefficient, if the polynomial gives perfect square value for all positive integer, then polynomial itself is square, that is, $P(x)=R(x)^2 $ for some integer coefficient polynomial $R(x)$**

Well, it is natural to think of the following question.

**Q. For all positive integers, $P(x)$ gives perfect $k$-power. is $P(x)=R(x)^k $  for some integer coefficent polynomial $R(x)$?**

I assume that it's true. Even though I don't know how to prove it. It's not what I want to talk about now.

**Q. For infinitely many positive integers, $P(x)$ gives square value. is $P(x)=R(x)^2 $  for some integer coefficent polynomial $R(x)$?**

The answer is false, hence one can think of $y^2=2x^2+1$, the equation has infinitely many integer solutions, thus being a counterexample.

However, once one notice that density of the solution is $O(\log x)$, (for which, above case, it is.) One also get the question of having dense enough solution, polynomial must be perfect power itself.

so here is my third question.

**Q. Denote the number of solution to the following equation as $C(x)$. if $C(x)>>x,$ then $P(x)=R(x)^2 $for some integer coefficient polynomial $R(x)$.**

Does this kindof theorem, topic, has a name? Is this already well-known? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if $P$ is irreducible :

step 1:$(P(x),P'(x))=1$ so there are polynomial $Q,R\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $QP+RP'=1$ if n was the g.c.d of denominators of the coefficients of $Q,R$ then $(nQ(m))P(m)+(nR(m))P'(m)=n$ so for each $m\in N$ , $(P(m),P'(m))|n$

step 2:$P(x+kq)=P(x)+kqP'(x) \hspace{0.25 cm} mod q^2$ if   $q|P(x)$ and P(x) was a complete power relatively prime to $n$ then $q|P(x+kq)$ but $q^2\not |P(x+kq) $

so you can find some bounds on $C_P(x)$ in your problem.

general case:

hint:if $P(x)=Q(x)S(x)$ and $(Q,S)=1$ use the same arguments as the step one to relate the $C_P(x)$ to $C_Q(x),C_S(x)$